# How do I disable drag and drop in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar throughout my project and i need to display it in one area of my site where events are not draggable but to remain highlighted in the month view. Any ideas please.

Comment: As of 2017 the correct answer is using: 'eventStartEditable: false'

Answer (score 41):

I know this is an old question, but nobody has answered this correctly, so here you go...

```
$('#example').fullCalendar({
    disableDragging: true
});
```

Comment: If you want to disable resizing as well as dragging, then you can set `editable : false`

Answer (score 23):

DisableDragging is replaced by: eventStartEditable  (since version 1.6.3)

Comment: I wanted to ask if there is a way to prevent selection dragging in month view-in other words the user must able to select only one monthday

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou sorry, I don't know that. I've done 99% of my work with day and week view.

Comment: I am just building an appointments web app and I want just to give my users the option of booking an appointments also from monthview...by selecting only one day(as an appointment by definition cannot span more than 1 day)...anyway,thanks for your answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer as for 2017. More info: https://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_ui/eventStartEditable/

Answer (score 18):

Check the code below:

*set editable false will disable dragging*.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

editable: false,

});
```

Answer (score 12):

You just need to set the [disableDragging option](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/disableDragging/) to true when initializing your calendar.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    disableDragging = true
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Not worked for me: `disableDragging: true`

The bellow code worked for me so please try:

```
$('#example').fullCalendar({
    eventStartEditable: false
});
```

The above code stops dragging of any event date to another date

Answer (score 4):

It's late but as per the new update in FULL CALENDAR

The `disableDragging` is depricated from fullcalendar now.

[Here is the list of all Deprecated functions in full calander](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/deprecated)

So to disable the drag you need to add `editable: false` in the place where you create the event object.

Something like below.

```
this.events.push({
    id: meeting.id,
    title: "meeting 1",
    start: meetingStartDate,
    editable: false
});
```

Answer (score 4):

place `eventStartEditable: false` as shown here:

```
initialView: 'resourceTimeline',
slotMinWidth:1,
eventDurationEditable: false, // Disable Resize
// disableResizing:false  Currently Not Working

eventStartEditable: false, // disable dreage drop
// disableDragging:false  Currently Not Working
eventTimeFormat: {
  hour: '2-digit',
  minute: '2-digit',
  hour12: true
},
```

Its Working

for More
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/disableResizing
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/disableDragging

Answer (score 3):

To disable event drag/drop conditionally (on a per-event basis) you can use the `eventAllow` option when initializing the fullcalendar object.

```
eventAllow: function(dropLocation, draggedEvent) {
  if (draggedEvent.id === '999') {
    return dropLocation.start.isAfter('2016-01-01'); // a boolean
  }
  else {
    return true; // or return false to disallow
  }
}
```

Reference: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventAllow

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable: false
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In v2 & v3 there is a new expression for this: [eventStartEditable](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventStartEditable/) what should be set to `false`, for disabling drag.

Furthermore if you want to disable the "drop" (e.g.: from other div) you should set [droppable](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/droppable/) to `false` as well.

Answer (score 2):

For version 5.5.1 you want to use `editable` property and set it to `false`. That will make sure events can not be resized or dragged.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on version :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  ...
 disableDragging: true,
 editable: false,
 eventStartEditable: false,
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

FullCalendar - Version 6, 2023  (**editable: true/false**)
"Determines whether the events on the calendar can be modified."
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/editable

```
let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: [ interactionPlugin ],
  editable: true
})
```

------- Global Bundle: -------

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
  // no plugin configuration required!
  editable: true,
})
```