# fullcalendar won't effect settings

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar throughout my project and I need to disable dragging, but enable click, I have tried the following code below, but without success

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    header: { 
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2014-01-12', 
    editable: true,
    eventStartEditable: false
});
```

Edit

It is possible to drag an even and click on the calender day, i need to disable dragging, but when i do, the click event dont fire

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        console.log(
        'Clicked on: ' + date.format + 
        'Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY+
        'Current view: ' + view.name
        );
     }
```

Comment: what you mean by enable clicking only?

Comment: i added more information

Comment: Do you have a Fiddle or something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I disable drag and drop in fullcalendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514689/how-do-i-disable-drag-and-drop-in-fullcalendar)

Comment: another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903140/how-to-disable-the-drag-in-fullcalendar-but-keep-the-ability-to-click-on-a-time)

Comment: @ebramtharwat I have read that post, and it does not work ad am using version 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the line  `editable: true,`

Here is a working example.
use this `script tag`.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    var Xmas95 = new Date("25 Dec, 1995 23:15:00");
    alert('vidda : '+ Xmas95);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        //editable: true,
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '20140210'
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
            }

        ],
            dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {

                    alert('Clicked on the entire day: ' + date);
                    console.log(date);

            }
    });

});

 </script>
```

this should work fine. The dragging facility will cut off by removing `editable:true`
and  **dayClick** can be achieved by the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [eventClick](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/eventClick/).

```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    header: { 
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2014-01-12', 
    editable: false,
    eventClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
        alert(
            'Clicked on: ' + date.format + 
            'Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY+
            'Current view: ' + view.name
        );
    }
   });
```